# How can I make drawer menu link to other fragment in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm not using standard drawer from android studio but I'm using `SlidingPanelLayout` to create drawer (I made from this tutorials https://nganthony.github.io/2016/01/24/implementing-android-mini-navigation-drawer.html)

My drawer is work well but I can't figure out how can I make button  link to another fragment

**I use this method to call fragment in standard drawer**

```
if (id == R.id.nav_sms) {
            SMSFragment smsFragment = new SMSFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                    R.id.layout_main,
                    smsFragment,
                    smsFragment.getTag()
            ).commit();
```

**My Project files**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.th.ac.sd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.ng.anthony.mininavigationdrawer.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**MasterFragment.java**

```
package com.th.ac.sd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.ng.anthony.mininavigationdrawer.R;

/**
 * Created by Anthony on 16-01-25.
 */
public class MasterFragment extends ListFragment {

    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_master, container);

        setListAdapter(new MenuListAdapter(R.layout.row_menu_action_item, getActivity(), MenuActionItem.values()));
        return view;
    }
}
```

**MenuActionItem.java**

```
package com.th.ac.sd;

/**
 * Created by Anthony on 16-01-25.
 */
public enum MenuActionItem {
    ITEM1,
    ITEM2,
    ITEM3,
    ITEM4,
    ITEM5
}
```

**MenuListAdapter.java**

```
package com.th.ac.sd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ng.anthony.mininavigationdrawer.R;

/**
 * Created by Anthony on 16-01-25.
 */
public class MenuListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuActionItem> {

    int resource;
    Activity activity;

    public MenuListAdapter(int resource, Activity activity, MenuActionItem[] items) {
        super(activity, resource, items);

        this.resource = resource;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;

        if(rowView == null) {
            rowView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(resource, null);

            MenuItemViewHolder viewHolder = new MenuItemViewHolder();

            viewHolder.menuItemImageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_image_view);
            viewHolder.menuItemTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_text_view);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        MenuItemViewHolder holder = (MenuItemViewHolder)rowView.getTag();

        if(position == MenuActionItem.ITEM1.ordinal()) {
            holder.menuItemImageView.setImageDrawable(activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_megaphone));
            holder.menuItemTextView.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.item1));
        }
        else if(position == MenuActionItem.ITEM2.ordinal()) {
            holder.menuItemImageView.setImageDrawable(activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_calendar_page_empty));
            holder.menuItemTextView.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.item2));
        }
        else if(position == MenuActionItem.ITEM3.ordinal()) {
            holder.menuItemImageView.setImageDrawable(activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_chat_bubbles));
            holder.menuItemTextView.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.item3));
        }
        else if(position == MenuActionItem.ITEM4.ordinal()) {
            holder.menuItemImageView.setImageDrawable(activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_college_graduation));
            holder.menuItemTextView.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.item4));
        }
        else if(position == MenuActionItem.ITEM5.ordinal()) {
            holder.menuItemImageView.setImageDrawable(activity.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_trophy));
            holder.menuItemTextView.setText(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.item5));
        }

        return rowView;
    }

    private static class MenuItemViewHolder {
        public ImageView menuItemImageView;
        public TextView menuItemTextView;
    }
}
```

**SNewsFragment.java (one of the fragment I wanted to link to)**

```
package com.th.ac.sd;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.ng.anthony.mininavigationdrawer.R;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class SNewsFragment extends Fragment {


    public SNewsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_snews, container, false);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.th.ac.sd.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main">

    <!--Master fragment-->
    <fragment
        android:name="com.th.ac.sd.MasterFragment"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_master">
    </fragment>

    <!--Detail layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="1000dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="56dp">
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

**fragment_master.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:divider="@null">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_snews.xml (one of the fragment I wanted to link to)**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.th.ac.sd.SNewsFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**row_menu_action_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_image_view"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know which file I should give so I give all the files in my project sorry

Comment: *My drawer is work well but I can't figure out how can I make button link to another fragment* which one , fab?

Comment: override onListItemClick from ListFragment  on MasterFragment.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

override `onListItemClick()` method from `ListFragment` on `MasterFragment.java` . Like

```
public class MasterFragment extends ListFragment {

    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_master, container);

        setListAdapter(new MenuListAdapter(R.layout.row_menu_action_item, getActivity(), MenuActionItem.values()));
        return view;
    }

@Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

            if(position == 0){
                SMSFragment smsFragment = new SMSFragment();
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                        R.id.layout_main,
                        smsFragment,
                        smsFragment.getTag()
                ).commit();
            }
        }
}
```